# NHibernate. Load Entity with 2 query and merge

Tags: nhibernate

I've got complex entity with a lot of children collection  of objects, which are complex too:

```
public class Order : AdvancedBaseOrder, ICheckable
{
    public virtual ICollection<RouteUnit> RouteUnits
    public virtual ICollection<Invoice> Invoices
    public virtual ICollection<Call> Calls;
    public virtual ICollection<Payment> Payments;
    ......
}
```

My payment class aggregates a lot of other objects

```
public class Payment:  ICheckable
{
    public virtual A A;
    public virtual B B;
    public virtual C C;
    public virtual D D;
    ......
}
```

I want get order with 2 queries:

1. load order entity without payments (FetchMode.Lazy)
2. load payments by order with joining its objects
3. combine\merger order with its payments

I don't want lazy load payments by nhib, cause I would like override fetch strategies for payment's objects.

So my question is how can i merge combine two result of queries in one aggregate
. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, `batch-size="25"` setting could do the job for you. Read more in the documentation: [19.1.5. Using batch fetching](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#performance-fetching-batch).

batch size coulde be applied on a *class* or *collection* maping:

Payment class

```
<class name="Payment" batch-size="10">...</class>
```

Collection of Payments

```
<class name="Order">
    <set name="Payments" batch-size="3">
        ...
    </set>
</class>
```

How the batching works in a nutshell: NHibernates loads the set of all `Orders`. Then based on a batch-size setting (e.g. 25) creates few calls to `Payments` filtered by `ID`s of just loaded *Orders*:

> WHERE OrderId in (@o1, @o2, @O3... @o25)

The merge will be done for you inside NHibernate session. From my experience this is most powerful mapping... Lazy & Batching.

Comment: I know about this tuning(bacth-size). But I need the way manage nhibernate fetch strategy when it is loading lazy entities